# JPA Map ManyToOne with JoinColumn over FEDERATED mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a big problem, we are working now on implementing single sing in a project. Our admin made some tables as `FEDERATED` in DB (`mysql`) and because of this app is throwing a lots of exception. How can I map in `JPA` a field with `ManyToOne` relation to that federated table ? It's throwing exceptions on update and on insert in table users for column `LOCALITY_ID` (where it must have only the id).

Error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: ......stuff

```
public class User extends BaseEntity implements IAccessDataAware, UserDetails, IAuditable {

    /** serial version */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2899839338023778586L;

    @Embedded
    private AccessData accessData = new AccessData();

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = Constants.COLUMN_NORMAL_LENGTH, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = Constants.COLUMN_NORMAL_LENGTH, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "CNP", length = Constants.COLUMN_CNP_LENGTH, nullable = true)
    private String cnp;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", length = Constants.COLUMN_NORMAL_LENGTH, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE", length = Constants.COLUMN_NORMAL_LENGTH)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", length = Constants.COLUMN_NORMAL_LENGTH, nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = Constants.COLUMN_MD5_ENCRYPTED_LENGTH, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD_OAUTH", length = Constants.COLUMN_ENCRYPTED_LENGTH, nullable = true)
    private String passwordOAuth;

    @Column(name = "SALT_OAUTH", length = Constants.COLUMN_ENCRYPTED_LENGTH, nullable = true)
    private String salt;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD_OAUTH_ALGORITHM", length = Constants.COLUMN_ENCRYPTED_LENGTH, nullable = true)
    private String passwordOAuthAlgorithm;

    @Column(name="digital_signature")
    private Boolean digitalSignature=Boolean.FALSE;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "PATH_AVATAR_IMAGE", length = Constants.COLUMN_NORMAL_LENGTH)
    private String pathAvatarImage;

    @Column(name = "PATH_AVATAR_IMAGE_ORIGINAL", length = Constants.COLUMN_NORMAL_LENGTH)
    private String pathAvatarImageOriginal;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<HistoryEvent> historyEvents;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOCALITY_ID")
    private Locality locality;


....... Getters and Setters


}
```

Thank you

Comment: What kind of exceptions? Update your answer

Comment: exception is above the class. i can't put here the hole stack.and the object is not null

Comment: Why do you cascade the locality of the user?

Comment: i removed cascade, put it again removed it again and so on but i have the same exception with or without cascade. it is an old code, it is not made by me. the only one thing that i want is to put in table on insert/update id of locality and when i select user to retrieve the localiti from locality federated table